# Firebase DeepLink not working in Android 13 Updated Devices

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, deep-linking

Our application utilizes Firebase deeplink to direct users to our platform. While the deeplink successfully navigates users to our app on Android devices below version 13, it appears to be ineffective on Android 13. The log from an Android 13 device is below:

Tested device : Oneplus 8T

Deep Link : https://jkg2x.app.goo.gl/lulumoney

```
Activity not found to handle Intent action [CONTEXT service_id=77 ]
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.lulu.luluone/com.luluone.lite.feature.splash.SplashActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2184)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1831)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5555)
    at hen.platform_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hem.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hix.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hem.public_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hen.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):3)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5508)
    at hen.platform_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at hem.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at hix.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at hem.public_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at hen.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6011)
    at hen.platform_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hem.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hem.public_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):2)
    at hen.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):3)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5978)
    at hen.platform_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at hem.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):1)
    at krq.x(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):4)
    at krr.onPostExecute(:com.google.android.gms@231114045@23.11.14 (190408-517566403):3)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-$$Nest$mfinish(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8355)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
```

Please help in finding a solution for this issue.

Comment: I have got a fix for the same: <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="Your Domain"
        android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>